# TypeScript: anonymouse class factory

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript

My TypeScript v2.2.

I have this class factory:

```ts
export class A { name: string; }

export function makeConstructor(name: string)
{
  const newClass = class extends A { };

  newClass.prototype.name = name;

  return newClass;
}
```

TypeScript throw error:

> Return type of exported function has or is using private name '(Anonymous class)'.

I can say that this factory returns `any` to hide error, but how I can explain what exactly returns?

I tried to write

- `makeConstructor<T extends A>(name: string): T`
- `makeConstructor<T extends typeof A>(name: string): T`
- `makeConstructor<T extends A['prototype']>(name: string): T['prototype']`

Comment: This code [works](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20A%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20makeConstructor(name%3A%20string)%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20newClass%20%3D%20class%20extends%20A%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20newClass.prototype.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20newClass%3B%0D%0A%7D) on TypeScript 2.1…

Answer (score -1):

When you use the Factory design pattern, you should probably want to shield the exact implementation class chosen by the Factory, and just return A (or its interface) instead. Therefore, I think returning A just does the trick, no need for generics etc...

Comment: I use this anonymous class factory to produce different **extended** classes from base class A. I want to know which one class prodeced.